# How to fill a shape with color in a way that doesn't follow the outline?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, fill

I have created this shape in Photoshop and exported as PNG:
[image: This is my image]

I then imported it to Illustrator and now I am trying to colour it exactly as the logo below. Any help?

[image: This is the image. Any help?]

Comment: If it's a raster image, then it can't be edited in Illustrator.  Is it a raster image?

Comment: Hard to say... What does your version look like?

Comment: It is not a raster image. It's a vector shape created using Photoshop.

Comment: The rat logo is what I wish to fill in a similar way like the "carrat" in the first image.

Comment: What format did you export it into?

Comment: Use the pen tool, pencil tool or curvature tool and draw it manually.

Comment: I exported it to Png

Comment: @XavierV - a PNG is a raster image.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand how vector graphics work; it's not the same as painting on a piece of paper, where every brush stroke covers what you are painting over.

You also have to shift your thinking a little away from filling shapes: since you can create independent objects, the outline can be a different object than the fill color object. See where I'm going with this?

You already have an outline object. It has open shapes, and although you can still fill it with color (it doesn't matter how at this point) it will follow the shape of the outline. Instead, create a different shape, fill it with the color you want and send it to the back of your outline object. This way you can get the same results from your first example.

Answer (score 3):

Draw **separate** objects.

**Fill** them with the colors you want.

**Stack** the objects on top of one another.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Not really good with photoshop on computer because I mainly use my phone for stuff try to make the entire shape transparent with the inside as well and use a brush on a different layer to replicate this look.