# Illustrator - Inner shadow/glow to only one side?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, appearance

[image]

How can I get an inner glow but only approached from one side like on the image, and not around the whole object?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105566/how-to-fill-a-shape-with-color-in-a-way-that-doesnt-follow-the-outline While it's not an *exact* duplicate question, the methodology is the same. You use *separate objects* and stack them. You don't use "effects".

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an "effect", "glow", or "shadow" filter. It's merely a series of vector objects stacked on top of one another.

[image]

You *cannot* create these types of shadows via effects or filters within Illustrator.